# Is it worth checking dead links?

Tags: discussion

I for one posted several links (PDF or HTML files) in several answers of mine or in comments, and it appears that many are just dead. I can fix some of them here and there, but I wonder: Shall we just update all of them using, e.g., the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/), or is there an established policy regarding dangling pointers on the SE network, and in particular on Cross Validated?

Comment: Whenever possible, I use the Wayback Machine to fix them.  I do it fairly commonly.

Comment: If you have given enough detail for the reader to put into their favourite search engine like the title and first author of an article then I think there is little cause for concern here.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have time for it, feel free to do so. When I notice such links and there is an easy way of replacing them with something that works, I do so. If there is no obvious way to solve it, I usually leave comment for OP noticing them that the link is dead.

Comment: (+1) Is the Wayback Machine the best (and only) way to go then? Sometimes I just delete link to PDF since I provided a full reference. i'm just wondering whether relying on WBM is really a good idea. E.g., links might fade away for good reasons, or not.

Comment: I don't know. If possible, I use more official sources, but also WBM sometimes.

Comment: That's what I do too. Was just checking if there's an official policy on SE nowadays.

Comment: No policy that I'm aware of.  A very few users routinely find dead links and suggest edits to replace them, an activity that obviously takes effort and for which I am very grateful.  When we make those changes we should try to include visible identifying information to help people track down the references the next time the links rot... .

Comment: Thanks, A fully qualified reference is probably the best option, as a default.